# How to call the async task in private void

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i am trying to save some text in a .text file but i dont know how to call the async Task save in private void save_Clic

```
private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    async Task save(string filename, string content)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Swift as a shadow");
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to mark your method `async Task` because you're inside an event handler. `async void` is fine for this particular use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the void method to async void, so that you can await it.

```
private async void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Save(filename, content);
}
```

Also you seem to be not using the parameters of the save method, which you need to. and follow .Net pascal case convention for method names. It should be `Save` not `save`.